# Bootstrap page form input with 3 columns (symetric)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since I am using bootstrap on this project, I would like to know if it is possible (I suppose so), to manage the form element to have 3 columns, because right now the HTML page looks ugly as hell with all the subsequent input fields under each other. So spreading widely would make more functional and efficient.

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create Orders</title>
<link href="/common/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/order-download/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/order-create/createOrder.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/order-create/createOrder.js" type="module"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content-container" class="container">
      <div id="delivery-address" class="content-page">
        <div>
          <form>                        
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="refNo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Reference No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-refNo" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Reference No">
                <label id="refNo-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="poNo" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Customer PO No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-poNo" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="PO No">
                <label id="poNo-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="companyname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="companyname" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
                <label id="companyname-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>                      

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-firstname" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                <label id="firstname-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                <input id="buyer-lastname" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                <label id="lastname-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="addr1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address1<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-address1" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Address1">
                <label id="addr1-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="addr2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address2</label>
                <input id="buyer-address2" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Address2">
                <!-- <label id="addr2-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label> -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="suburb" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Suburb<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-suburb" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Suburb">
                <label id="suburb-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select id="buyer-state" class="col-sm-4 form-control" >
                  <option select="selected">-</option>
                  <option value="New South Wales">New South Wales</option>
                  <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
                  <option value="Victoria">Victoria</option>
                  <option value="South Australia">South Australia</option>
                  <option value="Tasmania">Tasmania</option>
                  <option value="Western Australia">Western Australia</option>
                  <option value="Australian Capital Territory">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                  <option value="Northern Territory">Northern Territory</option>
                </select>
                <label id="state-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="postcode" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Postcode<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-postcode" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
                <label id="postcode-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <!-- <input id="country" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Country"> -->
                <select id="buyer-country" class="col-sm-4 form-control" >
                  <option select="selected">-</option>
                  <option value="AU">AU</option>
                  <option value="UK">UK</option>
                  <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                </select>
                <label id="country-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone</label>
                <input id="buyer-phone" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                <label id="phone-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
                <input id="buyer-email" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                <label id="email-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>                     

            <div class="form-group row" >
                <label for="deliveryNote" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">DeliveryNote</label>
                <input id="buyer-note" type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="DeliveryNote">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="store" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Supplier Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select id="buyer-store" class="col-sm-4 form-control"><option select="selected" >-</option></select>
                <label id="store-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Created Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-date" type="date" class="col-sm-4 form-control" placeholder="Created Date">
                <label id="date-feedback" class="feedback col-sm-4 col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get his to work, I placed the class `row` onto the form element; replaced all `row`'s on the `form-group` elements for `col-md-4`, which makes the form have three columns on tablets screens and bigger; and lastly, removed all `col-` classes from the label and input elements.

Below is your updated code. Copy & paste...

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create Orders</title>
<link href="/common/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/order-download/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/order-create/createOrder.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/order-create/createOrder.js" type="module"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content-container" class="container">
      <div id="delivery-address" class="content-page">
        <div>
          <form class="row">
          
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="refNo" class="col-form-label">Reference No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-refNo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference No">
                <label id="refNo-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="poNo" class="col-form-label">Customer PO No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-poNo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PO No">
                <label id="poNo-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="companyname" class="col-form-label">Company Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="companyname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
                <label id="companyname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="firstname" class="col-form-label">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                <label id="firstname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="lastname" class="col-form-label">Last Name</label>
                <input id="buyer-lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                <label id="lastname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="addr1" class="col-form-label">Address1<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-address1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address1">
                <label id="addr1-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="addr2" class="col-form-label">Address2</label>
                <input id="buyer-address2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address2">
                <!-- <label id="addr2-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label> -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="suburb" class="col-form-label">Suburb<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-suburb" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suburb">
                <label id="suburb-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="state" class="col-form-label">State<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select id="buyer-state" class="form-control" >
                  <option select="selected">-</option>
                  <option value="New South Wales">New South Wales</option>
                  <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
                  <option value="Victoria">Victoria</option>
                  <option value="South Australia">South Australia</option>
                  <option value="Tasmania">Tasmania</option>
                  <option value="Western Australia">Western Australia</option>
                  <option value="Australian Capital Territory">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                  <option value="Northern Territory">Northern Territory</option>
                </select>
                <label id="state-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="postcode" class="col-form-label">Postcode<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-postcode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
                <label id="postcode-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="country" class="col-form-label">Country<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <!-- <input id="country" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country"> -->
                <select id="buyer-country" class="form-control" >
                  <option select="selected">-</option>
                  <option value="AU">AU</option>
                  <option value="UK">UK</option>
                  <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                </select>
                <label id="country-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="phone" class="col-form-label">Phone</label>
                <input id="buyer-phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                <label id="phone-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email Address</label>
                <input id="buyer-email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                <label id="email-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>                     

            <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                <label for="deliveryNote" class="col-form-label">DeliveryNote</label>
                <input id="buyer-note" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DeliveryNote">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="store" class="col-form-label">Supplier Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <select id="buyer-store" class="form-control"><option select="selected" >-</option></select>
                <label id="store-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="date" class="col-form-label">Created Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input id="buyer-date" type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Created Date">
                <label id="date-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label hide"></label>
            </div>
            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to keep the labels/inputs as side-by-side, you would need what is called "nested columns." For this, copy & paste the following...

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create Orders</title>
<link href="/common/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/order-download/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/order-create/createOrder.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="/order-create/createOrder.js" type="module"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content-container" class="container">
      <div id="delivery-address" class="content-page">
        <div>
          <form class="row">
          
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="refNo" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Reference No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-refNo" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Reference No">
                    <label id="refNo-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="poNo" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Customer PO No<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-poNo" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="PO No">
                    <label id="poNo-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="companyname" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Company Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="companyname" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Company Name">
                    <label id="companyname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="firstname" class="col-form-label col-md-6">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-firstname" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="First Name">
                    <label id="firstname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="lastname" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="buyer-lastname" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <label id="lastname-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="addr1" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Address1<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-address1" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Address1">
                    <label id="addr1-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="addr2" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Address2</label>
                    <input id="buyer-address2" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Address2">
                    <!-- <label id="addr2-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label> -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="suburb" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Suburb<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-suburb" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Suburb">
                    <label id="suburb-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="state" class="col-form-label col-md-6">State<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="buyer-state" class="form-control col-md-6" >
                      <option select="selected">-</option>
                      <option value="New South Wales">New South Wales</option>
                      <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
                      <option value="Victoria">Victoria</option>
                      <option value="South Australia">South Australia</option>
                      <option value="Tasmania">Tasmania</option>
                      <option value="Western Australia">Western Australia</option>
                      <option value="Australian Capital Territory">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                      <option value="Northern Territory">Northern Territory</option>
                    </select>
                    <label id="state-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="postcode" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Postcode<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-postcode" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Postcode">
                    <label id="postcode-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="country" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Country<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <!-- <input id="country" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Country"> -->
                    <select id="buyer-country" class="form-control col-md-6" >
                      <option select="selected">-</option>
                      <option value="AU">AU</option>
                      <option value="UK">UK</option>
                      <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                    </select>
                    <label id="country-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="phone" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Phone</label>
                    <input id="buyer-phone" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Phone">
                    <label id="phone-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Email Address</label>
                    <input id="buyer-email" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Email Address">
                    <label id="email-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>                     

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="deliveryNote" class="col-form-label col-md-6">DeliveryNote</label>
                    <input id="buyer-note" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="DeliveryNote">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="store" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Supplier Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="buyer-store" class="form-control col-md-6"><option select="selected" >-</option></select>
                    <label id="store-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="date" class="col-form-label col-md-6">Created Date<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input id="buyer-date" type="date" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Created Date">
                    <label id="date-feedback" class="feedback col-form-label col-md-6 hide"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you so much. Is there a way to place labels and inputs in the same line?

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Please see the updated answer. You should be good to go. :-)